# Concepts behind MySQL cursor

Tags: python, concurrency, connection, cursor, mysql-python

Could someone please explain me the concept behind MySQL cursor, especially in the context of multiprocessing?

I am fairly new to python and am accessing a MySQLdb concurrently using a module with the same name. All my processes have own connections and own cursors, because i run into exceptions otherwise. I reuse cursors for multiple requests though.

What is the right pattern to access a MySQL concurrently?
Are there nicer (i.e. higher abstraction level) modules to use than MySQLdb?
What is the conceptual difference between a connection and a cursor then?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454337/how-do-cursors-work-in-pythons-db-api

Comment: See [PEP 249 -- Python Database API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for a description of the connection and cursor concepts.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right pattern to access a MySQL concurrently?

Every thread/process should manage its own connection to the database.

> Are there nicer (i.e. higher abstraction level) modules to use than MySQLdb?

You might want to check out [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org).

> What is the conceptual difference between a connection and a cursor then?

A connection represents your program's connection (d'oh!) to the database software.  The connection concept only provides means to handle transactions (commit and rollback) and to create cursors.  In particular, a connection does not need to provide means to execute SQL directly.

A cursor is needed to execute SQL using a connection and to retrieve/traverse the results.

See [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for details.