# Is a Python DBAPI cursor the same as a SQL cursor? If so how to improve the performance? What should be the alternative approach?

Tags: sql, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

We have a really big data querying process.
As of now we are fetching the data using raw sql queries and we are executing them in using a python db api cursor.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connection("DB_connection_string")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from so_so")
```

this has raised a the subject of performance issues and we believe these cursors are same as Sql cursors which are bad for the performance.

Are they same? If so, can some one please suggest a faster approach?

Is SQLALCHEMY or ORM pattern faster then this approach?

and also I have read SQLALCHEMY is built on such drivers which interact with database to form a layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do cursors work in Python's DB-API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454337/how-do-cursors-work-in-pythons-db-api)

Comment: but I was asking the possible alternative as well. There was not mention of alternative in the other question I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, normal psycopg2 cursors are not [PostgreSQL server-side cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html): they are lightweight client-side data structures holding the result of a query for the time needed by the client.

Server-side cursors can be used by psycopg using [named cursors](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) and not used by default.